# Swift: Extending UIStackView to create a centred list of tags

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'd like to create a centred list of tags, along the lines of this, but centred:

[image: Tags]

Image source: http://blog.gqueues.com/2013/07/android-vs-ios-comparing-development.html

I thought a nice way to do this would be to extend `UIStackView`, so that I can have an 'addData' function to do go through the process of creating a view and adding it to the stack. Here's the code so far:

import Foundation
import UIKit

```
class DataView: UIStackView {
    func addData(_ data: String) {
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.text = data
        label.sizeToFit()
        view.frame.size = label.frame.size
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't quite look right. The only way I could get the stack view to display the items was to set constraints on either the width, or left and right to force the width. I also needed to set the `Stack View settings to Alignment:Fill and Distribution:Fill Equally in order to see any of them.

[image: Stack view showing items filled equally]

My 
Does anybody have any idea how I can get a better result here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, the key to solving this was to specify widths of each of the views and use auto layout to centre the labels. Finally, I needed to calculate the total width, so that with the mode of the `UIStackView` set to Distribution: Equal Spacing, the items would be spaced out appropriately. Here's my final code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DataView: UIStackView {
    var widthRequired = CGFloat()

    func addData(_ data: String) {
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = uifont_notification
        view.backgroundColor = uicolor_verylight
        label.textColor = uicolor_dark
        label.text = data
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.sizeToFit()
        view.addSubview(label)
        widthRequired = label.frame.width + widthRequired + 24
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let labelView = ["label" : label]
        let formatString = "H:|-[label]-|"
        let formatStringV = "V:|-[label]-|"
        let outerView = ["view" : view]
        let formatStringW = "[view(==\(label.frame.width + 20))]"
        let constraintH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: formatString, options:.alignAllCenterX , metrics: nil, views: labelView)
        let constraintV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: formatStringV, options:.alignAllCenterX , metrics: nil, views: labelView)
        let constraintW = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: formatStringW, options:.alignAllCenterX , metrics: nil, views: outerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintH)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintV)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintW)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        self.addArrangedSubview(view)
        label.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

Used like this, within a `collectionView cellForItemAt` function

```
cell.itemData.addData("One")
cell.itemData.addData("Two")
cell.itemData.addData("Three")
cell.itemDataWidth.constant = cell.itemData.widthRequired // The width of the `UIStackView` constraint as a @IBOutlet in the custom cell
```

Hope that helps somebody. Here's what the final image looks like when in use:

[image: Showing the UIStackView extension in use]

Comment: Hey @Ben did you manage to have it grow vertically as well? So when the tags reach the end of the screen they would just stack bellow

Comment: Unfortunately not - I had to carefully limit the length and number of cells to fit the width of the screen. Sorry!